# Problems with scala regex extractor

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching, extractor

I have a problem with the regex extrator, this is my regex

```
val regex = """(some\/params\/results\/\b[A-Z]{3}\/[A-Z]{3}\b\/)*""".r
```

And when I try to do this:

```
val regex(res) = "some/params/results/XXX/YYY/2016-05-09/2016-05-18/1/0/0"
```

I get an:

```
some/params/results/XXX/YYY/2016-05-09/2016-05-18/1/0/0 (of class java.lang.String)
scala.MatchError: some/params/results/XXX/YYY/2016-05-09/2016-05-18/1/0/0 (of class java.lang.String)
```

I would like to use it in pattern matching like this:

```
url match {
  case regex(res) => res
  case _ => url
}
```

to extract the group `some/params/results/XXX/YYY/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add penultimate element dot `.` before `*`

Explanation:

`(...)*` - star at the end means: zero or more matches of content in the brackets.

`(...).*` - star at the end means: zero or more matches of `.`, where `.` is any single character.

Comment: it won't match in such case.

Comment: I suggest explaining the difference between the current regex and the fixed one.